# MISRA 2004 Required Rule 10.1, Prohibited Implicit Conversion: Non-constant argument to function

Tags: c, misra

I am changing my code to meet the MISRA standard. I have come across the warning

> Required Rule 10.1, Prohibited Implicit Conversion: Non-constant argument to function.

```
memcpy(&Final_buff[index], Main_cal, buffer_size);
// where buffer_size is uint8, uint8 *Final_buff, and const uint8 *buffer
```

Then I changed above for a small test:

```
memcpy(&Final_buff[index], Main_cal, 12u);
```

which is accepted by MISRA. The thing is I can't hardcode the value there. How can I get rid of this warning?

Comment: Show the declaration of Final_buff, Main_cal and buffer_size.

Comment: @work.bin, I have edited it. it is uint8 *Final_buff

Comment: Show the declaration for Main_cal too and mention the typecast that you already tried.

Comment: @harper, but Current Misra is throwing an warning on "buffer_size"

Comment: why do you use `uint8_t` for buffer size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should solve your MISRA problem:

```
memcpy(&Final_buff[index], Main_cal, (size_t) buffer_size);
```

Rule 10.1 doesn't allow an implicit conversion in several situations, including "the expression is not constant and is a function argument", which is the situation you were running into.